# imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 32 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, изображения, gd

Есть админка на yii2, через которую загружаются разные данные. Хранятся данные в БД. Есть разные страницы и все работали и работают, а на одной странице выходит ошибка

> imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Corrupt JPEG data: 32 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9

т.е. некое изображение на этой странице сломано. Поиски в интернете привели к тому, что нужно прописать

> ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', true);

или

> ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);

но это не помогало, да и проверка настроек указала, что значение gd.jpeg_ignore_warning и так равно 1.

Все изображения, что отображаются на данной странице, по-отдельности открываются в браузере. Проверила.

Можно ли как-то исправить эту проблему или единственный выход - заменить "сломанное" изображение?

Comment: а где вы прописываете `ini_set('gd.jpeg_ignore_warning', 1);`? Есть ли у вас доступ к php.ini?

Comment: @Peresada там же и так значение gd.jpeg_ignore_warning = 1. доступ есть ко всему. прописывала во многих файлах, что относились к данной странице. на данный момент пришлось просто удалить "сломанное" изображение